# How to use both Disjunction and Validation?

Tags: scala, validation, scalaz

Suppose I need to create an instance of `A` using the functions listed below:

```
case class A(x: X, y: Y, z: Z)

val makeX: String => Error \/ X = ???
val makeY: String => Error \/ Y = ???
val makeZ: String => Error \/ Z = ???

val makeA: (String, String, String) => NonEmptyList[Error] \/ A = ???
```

Since I'd like to accumulate the errors of `makeX`, `makeY`, and `makeZ` I am using `scalaz.Validation`:

```
val makeA: (String, String, String) => NonEmptyList[Error] \/ A = (s1, s2, s3) => {
  val x = makeX(s1).validation.toValidationNel
  val y = makeY(s2).validation.toValidationNel
  val z = makeZ(s3).validation.toValidationNel
  val a = (x |@| y |@| z)(A.apply _)
  a.disjunction
}
```

Unfortunately `.validation.toValidationNel` looks a bit awkward. How would you improve this code ?

Comment: Do you reuse the `make..` functions anywhere else in your code?

Comment: Interesting question, I posted a simple answer. I'd be interested in seeing other solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a helper function:

```
def vnel[A](a: Error \/ A) = a.validation.toValidationNel
```

you can now do:

```
val makeA = (s1:String, s2:String, s3:String) => 
  (vnel(makeX(s1)) |@| vnel(makeY(s2)) |@| vnel(makeZ(s3)))(A.apply).disjunction
```